# parameters constraint in numpy lstsq

Tags: python, numpy

I'm fitting a set of data with `numpy.lstsq()`:

```
numpy.linalg.lstsq(a,b)[0]
```

returns something like:

```
array([ -0.02179386,  0.08898451,  -0.17298247,  0.89314904])
```

Note the fitting solution is a mix of positive and negative float.

Unfortunately, in my physical model, the fitting solutions represent a mass: consequently I'd like to force `lstsq()` to return a set of positive values as a solution of the fitting. Is it possible to do this?

i.e.

```
solution = {a_1, ... a_i, ... a_N} with a_i > 0 for i = {1, ..., N}
```

Comment: You can replace the negative float values with zeros like `np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0].clip(min=0)`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: no, I want lstsq to find me a solution with only positive values. If I replace negative values in one solution by 0. as you suggest the fit doesn't match anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Non-negative least squares* is implemented in [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html).

```
from scipy.optimize import nnls

solution = nnls(a, b)[0]
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thx! (sorry I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation)